# How do I show a UIActivityIndicator above the searchBar in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to find out what the correct way is to add a searchBar and an activityIndicator to the top of UITableView (grouped).  The searches may take a few seconds to complete and I would like the activityIndicator to appear in a row above the searchBar and disappear once the search is complete.  The search is currently performed in the background.

My approach has been to create a UIView as the tableHeaderView in IB and to then create a UISearchBar in viewDidLoad and add it as a subView to the tableHeaderView.  This works fine and I could probably just do this in IB as well.

Then when the user selects the searchBar I am hiding the navigationBar and displaying the Cancel button in the searchBar.

When the user clicks the Search Button I do the following:

```
- (void)showSearchActivityIndicator:(NSString*)title {
    _activityView = [[ActivityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivityViewController" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context: NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

    _activityView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    _searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 44);

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 88);
    [self.tableView.tableHeaderView addSubview: _activityView.view];
    //[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -44)];
    [_activityView show:title];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Note that the ActivityViewController view has a UIView with the UIActivityView and a UILabel as subviews.

The problem here is that I can't seem to figure out how to make the tableview content itself scroll down when the ActivityViewController view is added.  I would have expected the tableView to adjust itself when the tableViewHeader height is altered, but that does'nt seem to happen.

Using setContentOffset seems to affect the tableViewHeader position as well.

What am I missing here or is my whole approach wrong?

EDIT: added screen shots showing what happens
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why is it that no sooner I have posted a question that I find an answer ?  Anyway I came back to this after a week or so and think I have figured it out.  Let me know if there is a better way.

Thanks to another post this seems to work for me, I hope its useful for someone else - still not sure if its the best way though.

The trick it seems is to make sure you reassign the `tableView.tableHeaderView` and wrap any changes in `[beginUpate] [endUpdate]`.  As you can see below I copy the headerView, change its height, add the ActivityIndicator and then set `tableView.tableHeaderView = view`.

Apologies for the poor formatting.

```
 - (void)showSearchActivityIndicator:(NSString*)title {
        _activityView = [[ActivityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivityViewController" bundle:nil];
        UIView *view = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context: NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

        float width = self.tableView.frame.size.width;

        _activityView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 44);
        _searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, width, 44);
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 88);
        [view addSubview: _activityView.view];
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view;
        [_activityView show:title];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    - (void)removeSearchActivityIndicator {
        UIView *view = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
        float width = self.tableView.frame.size.width;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context: NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [_activityView.view removeFromSuperview];
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 44);
        _searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 44);
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view;
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
         [UIView commitAnimations];
        _activityView = nil;
    }
```

[image]